Cannot prove the inequality from the textbook
Let $\xi$ be random variable. The moments $\mathsf{E}|\xi|^n<\infty$ for any natural $n\geqslant 1$. In the textbook an implication $$\varlimsup\frac{(\mathsf{E}|\xi|^n t^n)^{1/n}}{n}<1 \Rightarrow \varlimsup\frac{(\mathsf{E}|\xi|^n t^n)^{1/n}}{(n!)^{1/n}}<1$$
is stated ($t\in\mathbb{R}$).
The authors say the implication can be proven with the help of the Stirling's formula $$n! = n^n\sqrt{2\pi n} \exp\Bigl(\frac{\theta_n}{12n}-n\Bigr), 0<\theta_n<1.$$
I have substituted
$$\frac{1}{n} = \Bigl[\frac{1}{n!} \exp\Bigl(\frac{\theta_n}{12n}-n\Bigr)\sqrt{2\pi n}\Bigr]^{1/n}$$
into the lefthand inequality of the implication, and obtained
$$\varlimsup\left[\frac{\mathsf{E}|\xi|^n t^n}{n!} \exp\Bigl(\frac{\theta_n}{12n}-n\Bigr)\sqrt{2\pi n}\right]^{1/n} < 1.$$
Since
$$\exp\Bigl(\frac{\theta_n}{12n}-n\Bigr)\sqrt{2\pi n} \to 0, n\to\infty,$$
the implication is not apparent to me. What am I missing?

I can't see anything relevant about the probability context here. To me it looks as if there is a constant factor missing on the RHS.
A rather weak form of Stirling's approximation gives you
$$
\log(n!)=n\log n - n + o(n)
$$
as $n\to\infty$.
From this you get that
$$
\log((n!)^{1/n}) = \frac{1}{n}\log(n!) = \log n - 1 + o(1),
$$
and so
$$
\log \left(\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}\right) = -1+ o(1),
$$
or in other words,
$$
\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n} \to e^{-1}.
$$
It follows that whenever a sequence $(a_n)$ has
$\limsup \frac{a_n}{n} < 1$, then it also has $\limsup \frac{a_n}{(n!)^{1/n}} < e$ (but it's not in general the case that it must have $\limsup \frac{a_n}{(n!)^{1/n}} < 1$).

Are you sure this is the exact statement?
By Stirling's formula, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{(n!)^{1/n}} = e$, therefore
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{(E|\xi|^nt^n)^{1/n}}{(n!)^{1/n}}=
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{(E|\xi|^nt^n)^{1/n}}{n}\frac{n}{(n!)^{1/n}}= 
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{(E|\xi|^nt^n)^{1/n}}{n}\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{(n!)^{1/n}}=\\e\cdot \limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{(E|\xi|^nt^n)^{1/n}}{n},$$
and the statement should not be right.

James Martin, Lord-Schnitzel thanks!  Seems to be a typo in the textbook.
